# Python run command till button is pressed

Tags: python

Im programing in python 2.7 in kali linux i wanna run this command "airdump-ng" in my script but the command runs for ever until ctrl+c is pressed this is fine in the terminal but in python when i hit ctrl+c it exits out of the whole script not just the one command please help me with this i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: You need to catch a keyboard interrupt

Comment: `except KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: Why'd you tag "kali-linux"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
try:
  while True:
     print "running..."
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print 'Ctrl-C was pressed'

print 'one more line'
```

When you run this and press Ctrl-C, you'll get:

```
running...
running...
running...
running...
Ctrl-C was pressed
one more line
```